# How to make ImageMagick do this kind of halftone (see image and description)?

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop, dithering

Been looking at the halftone capabilites of ImageMagick. I've tried many combinations of *-ordered-dither* but without being near the result I want. I've tried Photoshop but that is not an option due to Linux platform and Licences and so on.

In Photoshop I get the result I want by making it *Grayscale* and then going through this line of choices: Image > Mode > Bitmap and *Method Use: halftone screen* with these parameters Frequency: *22 LPI* Angle: *55 degrees* Shape: *Round*

What would the convert command equivalent be for such outcome?

[The original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ8G4.png)

[Photoshop halftone made by clicking Image > Mode > Bitmap and the choosing halftone screen with these parameters Frequency: 22 lpi Angle: 55 degrees Shape: round](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adRxD.png)

Comment: https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#halftone

Comment: You can create custom dither patterns in Imagmagick. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#diy_threshold and the sections below it.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I found and read that page but I cannot reproduce with the settings I want. Can you specify the command you are using and possibly show your result?

Comment: @fmw42 I am aware that I can make custom dither patterns but I can't get this kind of pattern. How did you solve it?

Comment: @maggan What command are you using and in what way is the result you're getting lacking?

Comment: I have no specific solution. I was just suggesting that you could create a rotated dot pattern as a custom dither pattern with the approach listed on that link.